# redirect url with query string to path, and url without query string must be internally rewritten

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been trying and trying.

If one goes to:

```
www.domain.nl/vereniging
```

**internally** a page is requested from:

```
www.domain.nl/?p=vereniging
```

For that I use this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(p=.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ?p=$1 [NC]
```

If a users visits:

```
www.domain.nl/?p=vereniging
```

I want the users to be redirected to:

```
www.domain.nl/vereniging
```

For that I use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.nl/%1?     [NC,R=301]
```

(If I put *RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d* before this, it doesn't redirect anymore. That's strange because a query is not a directory right?)

Separately, these 2 chunks of code work.

However, if I put them together in 1 .htaccess it bitches about looping.
I don't understand this, because the conditions should prevent looping.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the END flag to either the first or second RewriteRule.

Look at the END flag here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: You mean [L]? Let me just remove them both. In my opinion, the conditions should make it loop-proof.

Comment: END seems to be more hardcore, but yes it does look like L should do it for you.  So actually I'm unsure

Comment: I removed all the [L]'s. I will adapt the above example accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check against the actual request:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?p=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhh
Screaming here right nowwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: I don't seem to have the 'reputation' to upvote you.

Comment: By the way, your code kicks me from http://www.richardhak.nl/rechten/ondernemingsrecht/?p=vereniging to http://www.richardhak.nl/vereniging.

Any idea how to stay in the same directory, without hardcoding the absolute path?

Comment: @user3059617 Try removing the `/` from `/%1?`, but I don't think that's going to work either as you need a `RewriteBase`. You may have to hardcode the path somewhere, either in the base or the rule's target.

Comment: I will play around with that a little. Why didn't the %{QUERY_STRING} work actually?

Comment: @user3059617 because the rewrite engine will loop, so when your rule that internally rewrites to `?p=something`, the next time around, the `%{QUERY_STRING}` condition will match against it. The `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is literally the first line sent as the request (e.g. `GET /?p=vereniging HTTP/1.1`).

Comment: Aha, the %{QUERY_STRING} will also be activated with an internal rewrite to ?p=something! Super!